# Login script with PHP and MySQL doesn't work, users from database doesnt appear - probably rookie mistake

Tags: php, mysql, login

I am new at php and MySQL, and I might have a stupid mistake here, but I just cant find it.... The script returns that I have entered wrong password or username, but I am completely sure that both are in the database, in table login, and are entered correctly. The mistake must be in the script..

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$db = mysqli_connect ("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "hobbybook")or die("Cannot connect to database");

//to check what user has written in form, make $username and $password using fields 'username' and 'password'
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//to take care of MySQL injection 
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//if result is one, corresponding username and password were found    
if ($count==1) { 

$_SESSION['username']=$username;
header("location:memberarea.php");
}
else {
    echo $username, " - you have entered wrong username or password";
    //header("location:login.php");
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging. Halt the execution using die() OR exit() and print the count result to see if everything is fine up to that point.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo $count;

exit(0);
```

**Steps for debugging :**

1. Check what $count is printing. If $count is not printing 1 then,
2. repeat the steps with $sql, Print $sql, copy the statement from browser and directly execute in phpmyadmin or mysql console. Check the result,
3. If you get some record then check connection